# Spring Security 'Roles' and 'Privileges' and Thymeleaf 'hasRole' and 'hasAuthority'

Tags: spring, spring-security, thymeleaf

Using [this](http://www.baeldung.com/role-and-privilege-for-spring-security-registration) approach, I had some troubles with the Front-End (Thymeleaf). An example:

- A user has role `admin` (the role is assigned with two privileges `read` and `write`)
- A user has role `user` (the role is assigned with only the `read` privilege)

In the Front-End I will secure different `div`s. If I login with an `admin`:

```
<li sec:authorize="hasRole('admin')">Entry 1</li>
<li sec:authorize="hasAnyRole('admin', 'user')">Entry 2</li>
```

shows nothing, while

```
<li sec:authorize="hasAuthority('read')">Entry 3</li>
<li sec:authorize="hasAnyAuthority('read', 'write')">Entry 4</li>
```

works perfectly.

Now as I am using the `role` as container for my `privileges`, is there no way to allow access to a `div` for a "whole" `role`? Do I really have to list all `privileges`? Or am I mixing something up here? Thanks.

The main idea is:

- user1

  ```
  with Role 'admin'

          with Privilege 'read' / 'write'
  ```
- user2

  ```
  with Role 'user'

          with Privilege 'read'
  ```

And in Thymeleaf:

Showing a div for all users with role admin with

`<li sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">Entry 1</li>`

and showing div for all uses with privilege write with

`<li sec:authorize="hasAuthority('READ_PRIVILEGE')">Entry 1</li>`

Is this even possible / 'the way to go?' I mean what is the sense of grouping privileges to a group (role) if I cannot give access to a page for the whole group?

Comment: It might be that Spring Security is automatically prefixing roles with `ROLE_`. What happens if you try `hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')`?

Comment: `hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')` has worked..I wasn't aware that in the DB the name of the role has to be `ROLE_ADMIN` too (as the prefix is automatically added I thought it can deal with just `ADMIN`)..

Comment: Spring 4 has made some changes to this. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-jc.html#m3to4-role-prefixing

Answer (score 6):

Normally, you don't need to include the `ROLE_` prefix.

However, when it comes to Thymeleaf, not only do you have to include it, it is also case-sensitive:

```
<li sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">Admin</li>
<li sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_USER')">User</li>
```

Also, an alternative to `ROLE_USER` (granted all authenticated users are given that role by default) would be to use `isAuthenticated()` instead, like so:

```
<li sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">Authenticated users can see this</li>
```

If you'd like to see what kind of roles are attributed to the current user, you can add the following to your page:

```
<span sec:authentication="principal.authorities"></span>
```

It should render an array of roles upon loading the page, e.g. `[ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN]`

[Reference](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springsecurity.html)

Comment: I got the hasRoleworking..however, this does not really answer the question..using the approach in the question, I would have to list all privileges of a role to show it, I cannot simply grant access for the "whole" role? Updated question...

Comment: @manu I'm unclear on what you're trying to say, you want to completely prevent a group from seeing a page?

Comment: I was wondering if it's not possible to grant access to role and to privileges when I follow the approach linked in the question. What is the reason to make a group 'admin' with the privileges if I have to list every privilege any way in Thymeleaf?

Comment: @manu You don't have to list every privileges. By default, everybody has access to everything in the page unless you specify otherwise.

Comment: I know but let's say I want grant access to every privilege but once and then I do need to list the privileges or not?

Answer (score 0):

Given your comments, I think it might have to do with a missing `ROLE_` prefix for your roles and/or a change in behaviour in Spring Security 4.

Roles are often automatically prefixed when populated. For example `DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator` contains a `rolePrefix` property which is by default set to `ROLE_` (see [the source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/5.0.x/ldap/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/ldap/userdetails/DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator.java#L143) and [these docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-jc.html#m3to4-role-prefixing)). Therefore, all roles retrieved via LDAP will be automatically prefixed. If this is the case in your situation of course depends on how you populate your roles.

Since Spring Security 4, `DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler` by default adds a `ROLE_` prefix to `hasRole(String)` and `hasAnyRole(String...)`  (see [the source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/4.2.x/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/access/expression/DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler.java)). For example, if `hasRole("ADMIN")` is used, then the role `ROLE_ADMIN` will be checked by `DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler`.

Using `hasAuthority("ADMIN")` does work, since no prefix is added for that expression.

So in your case, if your roles are populated **without** `ROLE_`, using `hasRole("ADMIN")` might actually try to match against `ROLE_ADMIN`, depending on the Spring Security version you use. This also affects Thymeleaf, since Thymeleaf is just using Spring Security functionality.